# C++: Quote escapes for an entire line

Tags: c++, text, format

I was wondering if there is any way to quote an entire line so that it shows the literal characters for `std::cout` in C++? I'm trying to make some ASCI art in a text adventure game i'm make, so that i could easily post ASCI art characters like at the top of this website:

https://www.asciiart.eu/

Comment: Can you show an example program that attempts to do what you're asking?

Comment: Are you saying you want to know how to get the escape character to show up in your string?

Comment: Lookup raw string literal

Comment: i was looking to make the escape characters show up, i found methods for making a single escape character show up, but for this ASCI art to work the whole line has to be literal.